# How to split a table based on values of variables?

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB table and I'm looking to filter it based on values in a single column.

An example of desired output would be, how would I split the table below into two, one containing all the `'Kinetic parameter'` and the other all the `'Species IC'`?

```
Var1    Parameters    Initial_guess    Lower_bound    Upper_bound       Variable_type   
    ____    __________    _____________    ___________    ___________    ___________________

     0      'Ka'          5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
     3      'Ki'          5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
     6      'PR1'         5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
     7      'PR2'         5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
     8      'alpha'       5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
     9      'Kcd'         5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
    11      'Klid'        5                1e-06          10000          'Kinetic parameter'
    17      'LR1R2_I'     5                    1          10000          'Species IC'
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll right, you can use `find` to find the row index of rows where Variable_type == 'Kintetic parameter', and filter by selecting the correct row index.

Comment: `find(T.Variable_type=='Kinetic_parameter')` complains that `==` isn't a valid operator for cell arrays.

Comment: Sorry, Try index = find(strcmp(T.VariableType, 'Kinetic_parameter'))

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this returns an empty matrix

Comment: weird, this works for me when VariableType is a cell Array. If it returns empty, it means that the function is fine, but the data matching has an error, i.e the string 'Kinetic_parameter' is not matching the Kinetic parameter in your Variable_type, do you want to check the spelling to make sure?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was being stupid. I'm use to putting an `_` at any opportunity I get which caused the empty matrix. Thanks for answering. If you write this up as an answer I'll accept it and give you some points (if you care about that sort of thing)

Comment: It's okay, I already got some rep today :D. Too much greed is bad. Good luck on your project.

Comment: as an aside, your `Variable_type` column is essentially a 'factor'. You might want to use a `categorical` variable instead of a string for that, makes things a lot easier.